# Program is not working after obfuscation

Tags: java, swing

I have created a Swing application with CustomScrollBarUI class. But after ofuscation program is not working as expected.Scrollpane UI is not changed. `UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", CustomScrollPaneUI.class.getName());` added in the **main**. Anybody having the solution please help...
Thanks in advance. (**ProGuard** is used for ofuscation)

```
public class CustomScrollPaneUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {

    return new CustomScrollPaneUI();
}

protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
    return new BasicArrowButton(orientation, Color.white, Color.white, Color.black, Color.white);
}

protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
    return new BasicArrowButton(orientation, Color.white, Color.white, Color.black, Color.white);
}

@Override
protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(trackBounds.x, trackBounds.y, trackBounds.width, trackBounds.height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(trackBounds.x, trackBounds.y, trackBounds.width, trackBounds.height);
    if (trackHighlight == DECREASE_HIGHLIGHT) {
        paintDecreaseHighlight(g);
    } else if (trackHighlight == INCREASE_HIGHLIGHT) {
        paintIncreaseHighlight(g);
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {

    if (thumbBounds.isEmpty() || !scrollbar.isEnabled()) {
        return;
    }
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    int w = thumbBounds.width;
    int h = thumbBounds.height;
    GradientPaint gradientPaint = new GradientPaint(0, w, Color.gray, w, h, Color.lightGray);
    g.translate(thumbBounds.x, thumbBounds.y);
    g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, 5, 5);
    g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
    g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, 5, 5);
    g2.setPaint(gradientPaint);
    g.translate(-thumbBounds.x, -thumbBounds.y);
}}
```

Comment: decrease the obfuscation level in Proguard and try again. In some cases, when obuscation level is set too high, Proguard obfuscates some literals and it leads to runtime errors.

Comment: To be sure, if you do _not_ set the ScrollBarUI in main, the application runs?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if at compile time this code

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", CustomScrollPaneUI.class.getName());
```

Is already resolved putting the un-obfuscated classname as parameter to the put method call.

However after obfuscating your classname changes and the UIManager does not know how to handle your obfuscated class name.

Comment: Try using following construct: `ScrollBarUI.class.getName()` instead of the string `ScrollBarUI`.

Comment: @ Rekin I used ScrollBarUI.class.getName(). But not working.Only After ofuscation the problem arises

Comment: Ok, it seems that at the bytecode level it doesn't make a difference or the root cause lies elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, I made one mistake: `getName()` returns `package.classname`, what wouldn't work without ProGuard as well. I should've written: `ScrollBarUI.class.getSimpleName()`, which according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName() returns only the class name, without preceding package.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation applies modifications to your bytecode, so things that rely on reflection may work not quite as expected.

General approach would be to play with [proguard obfuscation options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) (see Keep Options and Obfuscation Options sections) to keep classes/other bytecode properties from obfuscating to localize your problem.